# Pushing Results to KiwiTCMS using RobotFramework Ride Issue

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, kiwi-tcms, kiwi

I am trying to get Robotframework(Ride) work with KiwiTCMS.

I am making the connection to the KIWI server (local) but I am getting these errors that I am not sure where(In RIDE? or the .conf file?) to fix:

```
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'start_suite' of listener 'zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS' failed: ENVIRONFILE Version value not defined, missing one of TCMS_PRODUCT_VERSION, TRAVIS_COMMIT, TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SHA or GIT_COMMIT
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'end_test' of listener 'zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS' failed: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
TestKiwiRide                                                          | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KiwiTest.TestKiwi                                                     | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
KiwiTest                                                              | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\hendri\Documents\KiwiTest\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\hendri\Documents\KiwiTest\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\hendri\Documents\KiwiTest\report.html

(kiwi-env) C:\Users\hendri\Documents\KiwiTest>
```

Please assit?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in RIDE. This error `ENVIRONFILE Version value not defined, missing one of TCMS_PRODUCT_VERSION, TRAVIS_COMMIT, TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SHA or GIT_COMMIT` means a problem in the configuration of the listener. If there are no errors when running on the command line, then the same configuration must be done to the RIDE launcher (your own batch file).

Comment: Did you find a solution ? i'm facing the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details goes into the bat file you use to call the test cases

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check here : https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugins/automation-frameworks.html
In **plugin configuration** section, you have to passe configuration as environment variables. ***e.g.***

```
export TCMS_PLAN_ID=*PLAN_ID*
```